# workflow step for user Schedule a time for next step.?

Tags: aem

Do we have any OOTB workflow step that can take a user input (like Date selection) Schedule time to take in one workflow step and trigger the next step according to the scheduled time.
[image: Sample Workflow]

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to create a new page action like "Schedule for Review" in the authoring mode. See this https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-authoring-extension-header-backtosites
2. On click of the page. You can take the user to a custom servlet that will scheduler you workflow.

> @Reference

```
Scheduler scheduler

scheduler.schedule()
```

your workflow can be triggered using workflowSession

3. For the scheduled for approval step - use a dialog participant step and associate a dialog with your participant step. This will ensure your user inputs approval schedule date and time
4. Write a process step to attach another scheduler to your previous approval request you can use `@Replicator` to publish page at run time